# Get Random Element(s) from a List

Tags: elixir

I'm basically looking for an Elixir equivalent of Ruby's [`Array#sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#sample-method). Something that would let me do this:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

sample(list)
#=> 4

sample(list, 3)
#=> [6, 2, 5]
```

I didn't find anything in the [Elixir List Docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/List.html) either.

Comment: I understand what you're asking but I'm curious as to why such a function would be part of the standard Ruby library.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Updated Answer

As José Valim said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220622/get-random-elements-from-a-list/31229846#31229846), in `Elixir 1.1` and above, you can now use these methods to get random element(s) from a list:

- [`Enum.random/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1) - For getting single random element
- [`Enum.take_random/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#take_random/2) - For getting multiple random elements

**Example:**

```rb
Enum.random(list)                         #=> 4

Enum.take_random(list, 3)                 #=> [3, 9, 1]
Enum.take_random(list, 1)                 #=> [7]
```

*Remember to call `:random.seed(:erlang.now)` first!*

---

### Original Answer

I'm still unable to find a 'proper' and 'magical' way to do this, but this is the best I could come up:

**For getting a single random element:**

```
list |> Enum.shuffle |> hd
#=> 4
```

*Note: This gives an exception if the `list` is empty*

**For getting multiple random elements:**

```
list |> Enum.shuffle |> Enum.take(3)
#=> [7, 1, 5]
```

Comment: If you get warnings like "warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.", seed like this instead: `:random.seed(:os.timestamp)`

Comment: As of Elixir 1.2 you do not need to call `:random.seed/1` since Elixir uses the new [`rand`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html) module for this.

Comment: Hi, this is the author of the mentioned code. `Enum.random` / `take_random` was originally called `sample` (like in Ruby) and was merged to Elixir 1.1, later renamed. Worth mentioning is that it's **O(n)** with regard to the size of the enumerable, using a version of [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Relation_to_Fisher-Yates_shuffle) algorithm. It was my first contribution to the Elixir standard library - very good experience, guys have excellent standards with regard to reviews, discussions & the whole workflow. I really recommend contributing there.

Answer (score 12):

There is no such function in Elixir 1.0, so you need to implement it yourself as mentioned by the other solutions. However, `Enum.random/1` is coming with Elixir v1.1: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1

Answer (score 5):

Another way (for sampling one element only) is:

```
list |> Enum.at(:random.uniform(length(list)) - 1)
```

Possibly preferable over the other method if you're working with large enough lists that shuffling the whole list might have a performance impact.

*[Gazler's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220622/get-random-elements-from-a-list#comment50442963_31220789) about using `:random.seed(:erlang.now)` still applies.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a newer version of Elixir, there's the `Enum.take_random/2` function that was added in Elixir v1.1.

From Elixir's v1.1 [documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Enum.html#take_random/2):

> Takes random items from a collection.
>
> Notice this function will traverse the whole collection to get the random sublist of collection. If you want the random number between two integers, the best option is to use the :random module.

So, answering the question, taking multiple items from the list would look like:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Enum.take_random(list, 3)
#=> [2, 4, 1]
```

Or, for a single item:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Enum.take_random(list, 1)
#=> [1]
```